# dynamic refresh such that it remains where it last was left

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form at the right side of page. Table left side of page. When click submit form the php file directs it back to this original page where the form and table is displayed. This enable me to see the added data in the table. However, when table is long after the data in the form is added after the refresh it goes to the top of the page.

How to make it such that the

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
header("location:invites.php");
}
```

will bring back to where it last was and also refresh the page such that the data inserted will be the same

Comment: use ajax, so you dont need page reload, and also can update ,insert, delete, and refresh table and form